# $ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, \ f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed and open $\Rightarrow \ f(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f$ be a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $. Could you explain to me why the following is true?

$ f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed and open $\Rightarrow \ f(\mathbb{R}^n) = \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
For $X$ a connected topological space and $A\subset X$:
$A$ is closed and open $\Leftrightarrow A=\emptyset \vee A=X$

---

Now since $\mathbb R^n$ is connected and $f$ is a function...

Answer (score 2):

The only closed and open sets in a connected topological space, eg. in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To see that this is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$, suppose $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and nonempty and $X^c\ne\emptyset$. Let $x\in X$ and $y\in X^c$, and let $\gamma(t)=(1-t)x+ty$ be the straight line connecting $x$ and $y$. As you travel along the line from $x$ to $y$ you will eventually reach a point such that if you go any further along the line you will exit $X$, and this point will be $\gamma(t_0)=(1-t_0)x+t_0y$ where $t_0$ is the supremum over all $0\le t<1$ such that $\gamma(t)\in X$. Note that since $X$ is open $t\ne 0$. Now $\gamma(t_0)\notin X$ since $X$ is open and there is no ball around $\gamma(t_0)$ contained in $X$. But $\gamma(t_0)$ is a limit point of $X$, therefore $X$ isn't closed. So the only open and closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the whole set and the empty set.